# returning reference to class

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, return

I have code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class AbstractIterator{
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class AbstractList{};

class Iterator : public AbstractIterator{
public:
   Iterator(const AbstractList & list) : list(list){};

   virtual void do_something() override{
       printf("hello\n");
   };

   const AbstractList & list;
};

class List : public AbstractList{
public:
  Iterator getIterator(){
     return Iterator(*this);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    List list;
    Iterator it = list.getIterator();

    it.do_something();

    return 0;
}
```

This works, but I want to "push" getIterator() method to AbstractList class. To do so, need to be able to do following:

```
/* non const */
AbstractIterator &it = list.getIterator();
it.do_something();
```

Is this possible to be done somehow without dynamic allocation?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you need `AbstractList` in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I need it.  
This is part of very big code, I just isolated the problem in order to be easier for understanding.

Comment: How would you do this with dynamic allocation? I do not see how this is related to dynamic allocation.

Comment: @tobi303 - I can do it Java way - list.getIterator() use return (AbstractIterator *) new Iterator(*this) or it may return smart pointer to avoid explicit delete

Comment: "Yes, I need it." does not answer his question. It is really hard to know what you are trying to achieve. Your iterators do not look like iterators and the list does not look like a list, so either you have to explain what it is about or you make your minimal compilable example really **minimal**

Comment: @tobi303 voila - https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM3

Comment: ??? do you know the meaning of "minimal" ?

Comment: Pls, excuse me I did not wanted to be rude. I need to be able to return non const reference to Interface. I am new to C++11 and I do not seems to find online doc for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution could be:

```
class AbstractIteratorImpl{
public:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class Iterator {
pibluc:
    void do_something() { impl->do_something(); }
    friend class AbstractList;
private:
    Iterator( std::unique_ptr<AbstractIteratorImpl> &limpl ) : impl( limpl ){}
    std::unique_ptr<AbstractIteratorImpl> impl;
}

class AbstractList
{
    virtual std::unique_ptr<AbstractIteratorImpl> getIteratorImpl() = 0;
public:
    Iterator getIterator() { return Iterator( getIteratorImpl() ); }
};
```

I am not sure all argument/return types are correct, but I hope idea is clear.

PS Of course if you want to keep ownership of the iterator in the container you can use `std::shared_ptr` plus you may keep `std::weak_ptr` in `Iterator` and you would not have to implement `invalidate()` explicitly, that would be automagic.

Comment: decorator pattern? very interesting aproach, I like it

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this

```
class AbstractIterator{
public:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class AbstractList
{
public:
    virtual AbstractIterator* getIterator() = 0;
};

class Iterator : public AbstractIterator{
public:
    Iterator(AbstractList& list) : list(list){}

    const Iterator operator=( const Iterator& other )
    {
        list = other.list;
        return *this;
    }

    virtual void do_something() override{
        printf("hello\n");
    }

    AbstractList& list;
};

class List : public AbstractList{
    Iterator iterator;
public:
    List() : iterator( *this ) {}
    AbstractIterator* getIterator() override
    {
        iterator = Iterator( *this );
        return &iterator;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    List list;

    AbstractIterator* it = list.getIterator();
    it->do_something();

    return 0;
}
```

BTW. It is important to remember about iterator validness ( modification of lists, virtual destructors etc ), this example is very basic :)

This is written very fast

- invalidation function for iterator should be private, it can be done but it will complicate a little bit source
- notice that iterface method are called by template method - good habit

Source:

```
class AbstractList;

class AbstractIterator{
public:
    AbstractIterator( AbstractList* list ) : list( list ), valid( true ) {}
    virtual bool moveNext() = 0;
    void doSomething()
    {
        if( isValid() )
        {
            do_something();
        }
    }

    bool isValid() { return valid && 0 != list; }
    void invalidate()
    {
        valid = false;
    }
protected:
    AbstractList* list;
private:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
    bool valid;
};

class AbstractList
{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractList()
    {
        for( std::shared_ptr< AbstractIterator > it : iterators )
        {
            it->invalidate();
        }
        iterators.clear();
    }
    std::shared_ptr< AbstractIterator > iterator()
    {
        std::shared_ptr< AbstractIterator > it = getIterator();
        iterators.push_back( it );
        return it;
    }
private:
    virtual std::shared_ptr< AbstractIterator > getIterator() = 0;

private:
    std::list< std::shared_ptr< AbstractIterator > > iterators;
};

class Iterator : public AbstractIterator{
public:
    Iterator( AbstractList* list ) : AbstractIterator(list){}
    ~Iterator() {printf("Iterator cleaned\n");}

    virtual bool moveNext() override
    {
        if( !isValid() )
        {
            return false;
        }

        //do ...... iterate ... whatever

        return true;
    }

    virtual void do_something() override
    {
        printf("hello\n");
    }

};

class List : public AbstractList{
public:
    ~List()
    {
        printf("List cleaned\n");
    }

    List() {}

private:
    std::shared_ptr< AbstractIterator > getIterator() override
    {
        std::shared_ptr< AbstractIterator > iterator( new Iterator( this ) );
        return iterator;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    List* list = new List();

    std::shared_ptr< AbstractIterator > it = list->iterator();
    it->doSomething();
    if( it->isValid() )
    {
        std::cout << "It valid" << std::endl;
    }
    delete list;
    if( !it->isValid() )
    {
        std::cout << "It !valid" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is more less how should look like

Comment: Lives as long List class lives or new iterator is created ( getIterator() invoked ). This is reason why is stored as member of Iterator class btw.

Comment: ups sorry, was too fast. Its just too hot today for using ones brain. upvoted ;)

Comment: Robert, what I try to achieve is to have more than one iterator at a time for single list.

Comment: In that case I am afraid that you have to allocate it on heap because amount of iterators is variable and unknown. Besides 1. keep them in list/map 2.manage them in case of list change append/remove, list destruction. Strongly suggest rely on shared pointers. My example is only reasonable when you have one iterator per list. However it depends what do you have expectations from this iterator.

Comment: U mean example implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you mean is a non const reference to an object of abstract class type (in contrast to Java, C++ does not have interfaces, they are just pure abstract classes).

To return a reference, the object has to be kept alive somewhere. Thus, if your `AbstractList` is an interface (abstract methods only) I would not know how to do it.

Comment: so pointer or smart pointer are only solutions, and object will live in the heap

Comment: no, please do not use pointer when you do not need to, forget about my answer (maybe I will delete it) and take a look at Roberts.

Comment: didn't Robert have an error? return reference to temporary?

Comment: Also please do not delete the answer, I was about to accept it, just wanted 'discussion' about Robert's answer to finish

Comment: at first sight I thought it is a temporary but its not. And my mistake was to think that you cannot have the member in the abstract class. However, this is not needed, as you can store it in the concrete `Iterator` and the interface just provides the access to it.

Comment: Also, please do not accept my answer! You are giving me just another reason to delete it ;)